# Italian pronunciation of the symbol $dx$

Tags: pronunciation

I am afraid this question is going to be rather specific and perhaps off-topic, but I hope some of the Italian users (at least) can help me out with this curiosity.

I have always been used to the Italian pronunciation "de ics" of the differential $dx$. In principle there would be nothing wrong in saying "di ics", as the letter "d" is pronunced "di", but then why do the Italians say "de ics"?

Comment: Never thought about that. Maybe because $dx$ is “differenziale di x”

Comment: Maybe try https://italian.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @EricWofsey Many thanks, I will.

Comment: They actually say "de icse"

Comment: @uniquesolution Never heard that "e" at the end.

Comment: @uniquesolution Never heard either, just [de iks] or [dε iks] depending on the regional inflection. I'd say [de ikse] sounds silly, if not cartoonish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It largely depends on where the $dx$ is. As a differential, it is often pronunciated [di: iks] or [de iks].
When it's used in the derivative $\frac d{dx} $ it's almost always [de iks], since the whole thing is pronunciated [de in de iks].

$x$ is never [ikse] unless one wants to mock some regional dialect.